# Spring boot login page with org_name, username and password

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a login mechanism where in the login page I accept these 3 fields-
org_name, username, password.

While I have successfully been able to login using just the username and password combination, I need to check the combination of org_name & username, which is like a unique key in the users table.

I have explored Spring-boot's JDBC authentication, JPA authentication but just couldn't get it right.

For JDBC authentication based custom query, I am not able to fetch the 'org_name' parameter to be passed in the custom query.

P.S.: I am new to Springboot framework, so excuse me if the question is too noob. But I kinda need urget help on this.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields

Comment: @meriton, thanks, I am going through this and though it does what I am looking for, it is a bit complicated approach. Looking for something more clean and easy. Otherwise, would have to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then set up a WebSecurityConfig.java class

```
package com.example.securingweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

This was the general code I used while learning the spring security.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks Rohith for your answer but I am not looking for basic username, password based login. That I am able to implement successfully. Here I am looking for the ability to use more that these two fields. 
I believe the answer lies in the link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields but it is a bit complicated approach. Looking for something more clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do a little more work here. for username/password based authentication spring security use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. so you have to extend this filter and override the `attemptAuthentication` method where you will have access to the http request object.here you will have access to your extra 'org_name' parameter. then you need to implement the 'Authentication' interface where you will put your extra parameter. then from `attemptAuthentication` method you need to return an instance of your custom authentication object. you also need to provide your own authentication provider which will use this authentication object to authenticate the user.

Comment: Custom approach in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields blog talks about the same and I believe this is the solution. Thanks.